# wrong output in python code +1 ist not appear in output

Tags: python, output

I try to write a code :

```
command+="response ANY sip-header Remote-Party-ID modify  \"<sip:+\1@ " + get_ip(my_row_num) + " >\"\n"
```

in the output I can not get `***+\1***`.

Does someone know, where is my failure in this code ?

Best regards

Comment: `\1` is an escape symbol, so if you need `\1` in the string, write `\\1`.